# How to obtain coordinates for all the selected point data?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I have a selected points and I want the syntax for the finding the coordinates for the point data.

```py
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/Desktop"

in_point2 = 'C:/Users/Dallas_Property_Points_Part-3.shp'

field_nm = 'Remarks'
value = 'Move'
selection = "{field_nm} = '{value}'".format(field_nm=field_nm, value=value)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_point2, "NEW_SELECTION", selection)
```

Comment: Obtain how? Do you want to save them in a new table or just print them?

Comment: What happens when you run the code that you've presented?

Comment: I have to calculate the coordinates of the Point_2 file and check with the coordinates of the raw point_1 file and export the points that arent 'Moved'

Answer (score 3):

A simpler solution is to add the XY directly to the dataset. You appear to be using an older version of ArcMap so suggest you explore [How To: Calculate latitude and longitude for point features](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008944) using the calculate geometry tool.

If you are using ArcGIS Pro you can use the [Add Geometry tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm) instead